# Installing rx.net in .net4.0 project without nuget

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, rx.net

I have a c# .net 4.0 project that is developing on disconnected machine, so I cannot use nuget, but I can download software from the internet on other connected machine and move it to the disconnected one.
1. Which version of reactive extension (rx.net) should I download?
2. How can I use it in my c# .net 4.0 project? (which reference and from where to add it?)

Comment: Download last (for 4.0) and add reference

Comment: Btw you can add nuget on PC with internet and after this move you project to PC without internet.

Answer (score 1):

Install System.Reactive version 3.1.1 via NuGet and it should work,

https://www.fuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/3.1.1

Please say goodbye to .NET Framework 4.0, as Microsoft now requires all to use 4.5.2 and above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Of course I prefer to work with higher version of .net but my main customer still works with windows xp (which is also not supported... I know but those are my constraints… :( )